# Create Pipeline for GStreamer for USB Camera MJPG format

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer, nvidia-jetson

I have `Jetson Nano` and I would like to save a video from my `usb-camera`.
I had a problems with `MJPG` output from camera -it was outputting `YUYV` not `MJPG`, but I was able to solve it with `io-mode=2` settings for `pipeline`

This working in my `Opencv` (4.5.1)

```py
cap = cv2.VideoCapture ('v4l2src device=/dev/video0 io-mode=2 ! image/jpeg, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=30/1 ! nvv4l2decoder mjpeg=1 ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw,format=BGRx ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=BGR ! appsink', cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
                           
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MPEG')
    width = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
    height = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
    fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    print("fourcc:{} fps:{}@width:{}@height:{}".format(fourcc, fps, width, height))
    file_name = "abc.avi"
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(file_name, fourcc, 30, (1920, 1088))
    counter = 0
    while True:
        if counter > 200:
            break
        counter +=1

        _, frame = cap.read()
        if(frame is None):
            continue


        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        
        out.write(frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
        
       
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But the video is too laggy, because of that converts?, it prints 30fps but it saves like 4 frames for 10 sec video. And it also getting `1088` from `CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT`, idk why...

I found this `pipeline` works without `lags` in terminal

```sh
$ export DISPLAY=:0 (or DISPLAY=:1)
$ gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 io-mode=2 ! image/jpeg, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080 !  nvjpegdec ! video/x-raw ! xvimagesink
```

But I'm not able to use it in `opencv`

It outputting empty `pipeline` like

```sh
[ WARN:0] global /home/suomi/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (824) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: cannot find appsink in manual pipeline
[ WARN:0] global /home/suomi/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (501) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
fourcc:1195724877 fps:0.0@width:0.0@height:0.0
```

Also I tried this one, it works in terminal, but shows black frames when I'm using `opencv` like this

```py
'v4l2src device=/dev/video0 io-mode=2 ! image/jpeg, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080 !  nvjpegdec ! video/x-raw ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! appsink', cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER
```

My camera settings are here

```sh
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
    Index       : 0
    Type        : Video Capture
    Pixel Format: 'MJPG' (compressed)
    Name        : Motion-JPEG
        Size: Discrete 1920x1080
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 1280x720
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 800x480
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 640x480
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 640x360
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 320x240
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 176x144
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 800x600
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 1920x1080
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)

    Index       : 1
    Type        : Video Capture
    Pixel Format: 'YUYV'
    Name        : YUYV 4:2:2
        Size: Discrete 640x480
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 640x360
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 320x240
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 176x144
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 640x480
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
```

Comment: I also encountered the same problem. I resolved it by replacing nvjpedec to jpegdec.